# ASP ProcessModel and WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7, processmodel

If I have a WCF service hosted within IIS7; is it governed by the machine.config processmodel settings the same that an ASP.NET site or service would be?

Would those settings in effect govern the bounds of that WCF service? Regardless of what the endpoint binding configurations specify?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not trying to achieve anything. I'm investigating a production issue and I'm looking for an answer as to whether the processModel settings dictate the available numbers of worker threads etc  that are available to a WCF service hosted on that machine. i.e. ultimately set the outer bounds within which that WCF service can function.